# Legend in a bar plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

How can I plot a legend in a bar plot in Matlab? Here is the code:

```
Y = [1.5056
0.72983
3.4530
3.2900
1.4839
12.9 ];
n = length(Y);
h = bar(Y);
colormap(summer(n));
grid on

l = cell(1,6);
l{1}='L'; l{2}='B'; l{3}='R'; l{4}='P'; l{5}='h'; l{6}='Ri';    
legend(h,l);
```

This give an error: *Warning: Ignoring extra legend entries.* I tried solutions which I found on the [SO](http://stackoverflow.com) and web, but I couldn't resolve this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of legend, you can solve it using the tick labels for example:

```
set(gca,'xticklabel', l)
```

[image]

This will label each bar. If you want to use `legend` you need to have a matrix data, so the bar plot will show several bars per entry. For example

```
Y=rand(10,6)
h = bar(Y);
colormap(summer(n));
grid on
l = cell(1,6);
l{1}='L'; l{2}='B'; l{3}='R'; l{4}='P'; l{5}='h'; l{6}='Ri';    
legend(h,l);
```

[image]

Or, you can use different `bar()` calls in this way:

```
h = bar(diag(Y));
```

But then you'll get a displacement per each bar:

[image]

So, the only way really to do that using `legend` is to plot each `bar` seperatly, similar to what is discussed [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/176).

Comment: But this give me this text on x axes. The problem is I must place other text there. EDIT. Do you mean that I can't use legend on a vector data?

Comment: see my edited answer, basically you cannot do what you want using legend when you use bar() with a row or column vector. Internals of how legends are handled are described in MATLAB documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Further to bla's answer, you can use

```
h = bar(diag(Y),'stacked');
```

if you want to avoid the displacement.