# How to add legend on a bar chart?

Tags: matlab

I have the following Bar chart:[image]

Code to create it:

```
names = {'a', 'b',.....}
b = bar(cell2mat(data_plot'));
legend(b,names,'Location', 'eastoutside');
ylabel('Teest');
```

So, I want to add a legend to it, but not from each of the bars (blue, yellow, orange) but for the groups of bars(1, 2, 3 ,4 ...)
In names are saved all the names for the 12 groups, but I dont know how to set them as values for the legend. Instead I get other values that are describing each of the bars?

**UPDATE:** To be more clear, I don't want to change the values on the x-aches (1,2,..) with values from *names*. I want the (1,2..) to stay where they are and how they are, but instead I want to change the table on the right where I have a legend for the Blue, Orange and Yellow bars with values that would correspond to the (1,2,3..) with the ones from names.
Example: 1 are data from 'USA' so the first value in *names* is 'USA'. This means on the table on the right I want sth like 1: 'USA'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do what you want directly, you need to plot each group at a time, see [this related post](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/176-how-do-i-change-the-colors-in-a-legend-on-a-bar-plot-when-i-change-the-colors-of-the-bars) on MATLAB Answers and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697525/legend-in-a-bar-plot-in-matlab) on SO. Here's a workaround based on this, but the bars in each group have to be the same colour:

```
Y = rand(5,3);
names = {'a';'b';'c';'d';'e'};
colours = {'g';'r';'b';'y';'c'};
h = zeros(size(Y));
for k = 1:size(Y,1)
  h(k,:) = bar(3*k-2,Y(k,:),colours{k});
  hold on
end

xlim([0 15]);
set(gca,'XTick',[1 4 7 10 13]);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'1';'2';'3';'4';'5'});
ylabel('Test');

legend(h(:,1),names,'location','northeastoutside')
```

which produces the following:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT: Leaving for Legacy's sake. Ignore.** I misunderstood the problem and jumped to an answer I thought of instead of taking the time to read and test a solution.

Try `set(gca, 'xticklabel', names);`

Also be sure to check out the following on why:

- [Video on how to change xtick marks](https://www.mathworks.com/videos/setting-custom-tick-labels-97233.html)
- [Matlab Set Documenation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html)
- [Matlab GCA Documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gca.html)

Comment: thank you for the replay. But that is still not what I look for. I will update the question for better understanding